# Asymptotic Curves and Lines of Curvature of Helicoid (2)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, surfaces, curvature

I am dealing with this problem: [Asymptotic Curves and Lines of Curvature of Helicoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733441/asymptotic-curves-and-lines-of-curvature-of-helicoid). It's the question 3.3.2 from Do Carmo's book Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces.

I done the calculus finding:

$$e=g=F=0\\
E=v^2+c^2\\
G=1\\
f=\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{v^2+c^2}}$$

So, putting the values into the equation for curvature lines:

$$\begin{vmatrix}(v')^2& -u'v'& (u')^2\\ E& F& G\\ e& f& g\end{vmatrix}= 0,$$

I've got:

$$(u')^2(v^2+c^2)=(v')^2$$

$$(u')\sqrt{v^2+c^2}=\pm v'$$

$$\log((u')\sqrt{v^2+c^2}\pm v')=ctc.$$

Maybe it is obvious, but I am not understanding how go from here to the book answer: $\log(v+\sqrt{v^2+c^2})\pm u=ctc.$ Or maybe my calculus are wrong...

Many thanks in advance for some clue.

Comment: Where did your last equation come from? How did you integrate the differential equation?

Comment: In fact the last equation does not have sense. I am trying fix.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I was making a big mistake (I'm not very used to ODEs, I just have a very basic course in it theme), now I looked again and I could understand. Thank you for your attention once again, Mr. Shifrin.